# Can I connect a single color LED string to a RGB DMX512 controller?

Tags: led-strip, rgb, dmx512

I am planning on doing a bit of a light show this christmas on my house, I have ordered a bunch of 5050 RGB LED Strings, DMX controller, DMX Bridge and will be running the show using Vixen software.

Now, I already have some single color (2 pin) LED strings and I would like to use these too to make things like Stars, Mini Trees etc. Is it possible to connect a 2 pin string to a RGB controller? I am presuming I would simple hook one wire (Ground) to the V+ connection on the controller and the positive wire to any of the R, G, or B connections on the controller?

Hopefully someone can give me some insight into this as I am in the planning process, and want to be able to set up the sequence as soon as I can so I can test it out when my Bridge and Controller arrive in a few weeks, and hopefully be able to include the single color 2 pin LEDs in it.

Comment: Connect the Ground (negative) wire of the light strip to the Ground (negative) terminal of the light controller or power supply, NOT to the V+ terminal!

Comment: You saved me some head scratching, Thanks @PeterBennett, I will connect to the ground on the controller since the power unit will be housed in a separate box.

Comment: Hey @PeterBennett, I just got around to trying this. What you suggested did indeed work, but I needed to control when the led strip came on and off. So to do that, I needed to connect the + of the LED strip to the V+ connection on the controller, and the common to any of the R, G, B on the controller. Thanks for your answer tho, it did stop me from connecting them backwards.. cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was posted a long time ago but was never *really* answered.

But to answer; Yes! this will work just fine. The LED doesn't care what kind of signal it receives because all it wants is power. Which is exactly what your DMX RGB bridge provides. It literally "bridges" the digital DMX signal and converts it into an analog RGB signal. Technically, it converts it into just an analog power signal, but in this case, the bridge has the outputs marked RGB. Handy.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, Chris. He asked whether or not his RGB DMX bridge could be used to power a single (Non-RGB) led. And in my answer, I explained that he _could_ use DMX _with_ his DMX bridge to control a single LED with DMX. The only difference is that it will not be RGB, and he will have to decide which output he plugs into, whether it be the R port, the G port, or the B port. And then make a note of that so that he knows that DMX channel 1 (R) is connected to LED 1, and DMX channel 2 (G) is connected to LED 2 and so fourth.